# Why can we set the external momenta to zero while calculating the 1-loop correction to non-abelian theory coupling?

Tags: renormalization, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-analysis, singularities, dimensional-regularization

Refer to the second diagram in figure 73.2 on page 440 of Srednicki's Quantum Field Theory book. On page 441 he proceeds to calculate the amplitude and argues that since the divergent part is independent of the external momenta, we may set it to zero.

It is obvious that the terms with external momenta on the numerator are convergent (and may be ignored) since, by superficial analysis, the most divergent terms (which have $\ell^2$ on the numerator) are logarithmic divergent.

My doubt is: how can we know that the external momenta appearing in the horrible denominator won't produce external momenta dependence on the divergent terms?

I suspect the answer comes from dimensional analysis but cannot see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UV-divergences are caused by integrating over a large loop momentum $\ell$. In this region $\ell$ dominates the external momentum $k$ both in numerators but also in denominators. The latter can e.g. be seen by Taylor expansion. The second diagram in Fig. (73.2) is logarithmic UV-divergent, so subdominant ($k$-dependent) contributions are necessarily finite.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; Fig. (73.2)+eq. (73.6). A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).

Comment: Thank you! But, in that case, can't we also ignore the mass on the fermionic propagator's denominator?

Comment: As far as the UV-divergence goes: Yes.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why Srednicki explicitly kept it, then?